# Синонимизировать [копирайт]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки [копирайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) (5 вопросов) и [copyright](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright) (14 вопросов).

Comment: [tag:авторские-права] быть может?

Comment: @aepot есть ещё [tag:авторство] в эту коллекцию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пообъединял и синонимизировал в сторону [[авторские-права]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0/synonyms).

С учетом информации из комментариев.